# App script failing to bring data from another spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This program tries to bring all the data in one spreadsheet and paste it into another spreadsheet.
Firstly, it gets all files inside a folder (all of which will be spreadsheets), then it gets the values of a certain range and stores them into an array; after that, it goes to another spreadsheet and tries to set the values of the array into the first row with no data; finally, it moves the file where the data was stored in the first place.

```
var uploadG = DriveApp.getFolderById('')
var moveToG = DriveApp.getFolderById('')

function obtainAndImportData(uploadFolder){
  var internalFiles = uploadFolder.getFiles()
  while (internalFiles.hasNext()){
    var file = internalFiles.next()
    var fileID = file.getId()
    var copySheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID).getSheets()[0] // reads file by file and gets their first spreadsheet

    var Cvals = copySheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues() 
    var lastToValue = Cvals.filter(String).length-2 // gets last row with data

    var Csheet = pasteSheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues()
    var lastSheetToValue = Csheet.filter(String).length  // gets last row with data

    var allRows = []
    for (i = 0;i = lastToValue;i++){
      allRows[i] = copySheet.getRange(`B${i+3}:P${i+3}`).getValues()
    } // gets row and then stores it into an array

    var rangeToUnify = pasteSheet.getRange(`B${lastSheetToValue+1}:P${lastSheetToValue + lastToValue + 1}`) 
    rangeToUnify.setValues(allRows)  //inserts data from old spreadsheet into this new one

    file.moveto(moveToG) // moves file
  }
}
```

I think it should work fine, but the program just never completes its execution. Never inserts the data, and never moves files, but it doesn't throw any error either.

Note: The files this program is reading start as .xslx files, which are saved as Google Spreadsheets once they're uploaded to Google Drive. (maybe that is the problem, but I don't really know how to solve it)

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger feature to figure out where your variables start to not display the expected values?

Comment: Debugger also gets stuck and never ends the process. I ended up Cooper's solution but also changed the for loop from ` for (i = 0;i = lastToValue;i++){.....} ` to ` for (i = 0;i < lastToValue;i++){.....} ` as suggested by Tanaike

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a little closer to what you were shooting for

```
function obtainAndImportData(uploadFolder) {
  var uploadG = DriveApp.getFolderById('')
  var moveToG = DriveApp.getFolderById('')
  var internalFiles = uploadFolder.getFiles()
  while (internalFiles.hasNext()) {
    var file = internalFiles.next()
    var fileID = file.getId()
    var copySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
    var Cvals = copySheet.getRange("C1:C" + copySheet.getLastRow()).getValues()
    var ldr = Cvals.length;
    var Csheet = pasteSheet.getRange("C1:C" + pasteSheet.getLastRow()).getValues()
    var lstv = Csheet.length;
    var allRows = []
    for (i = 0; i = ldr; i++) {
      allRows.push(copySheet.getRange(`B${i + 3}:P${i + 3}`).getValues()[0]);
    } 
    pasteSheet.getRange(lstv + 1,2,allRows.length,allRows[0].length).setValues(allRows);
    file.moveto(moveToG) // moves file
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, in your for loop, you are using `for (i = 0; i = lastToValue; i++) {`. In this case, the loop is not finished.

  - I thought that this might be the reason for your issue of `but the program just never completes its execution. Never inserts the data, and never moves files, but it doesn't throw any error either.` is due to this.
  - In this case, it is required to be modified to `for (i = 0; i < lastToValue; i++) {`. But, when `allRows[i] = copySheet.getRange(`B${i + 3}:P${i + 3}`).getValues()` is used in a loop, the process cost will become high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
  - Also, when `rangeToUnify.setValues(allRows)` is used in a loop. the process cost becomes high.
- In order to retrieve the values from the sheet, you are using `copySheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues()` and `pasteSheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues()`. In this case, all rows over the data range are retrieved. In this case, the process cost becomes high.
- And, even when the above script was modified, I think that an error occurs at `rangeToUnify.setValues(allRows)`. Because the number of rows are different between the range and the values.
- And, `file.moveto(moveToG)` should be `file.moveTo(moveToG)`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please set the variables of `pasteSheet`, `uploadFolder` and `moveToG`.

```js
function obtainAndImportData() {
  var pasteSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("###"); // Please set your "pasteSheet".
  var uploadFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('###'); // Please set your folder.
  var moveToG = DriveApp.getFolderById('###'); // Please set your folder.

  // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639
  Object.prototype.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
    const search = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, this.getMaxRows()).createTextFinder(".").useRegularExpression(true).findPrevious();
    return search ? search.getRow() : offsetRow;
  };

  var internalFiles = uploadFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  var values = [];
  while (internalFiles.hasNext()) {
    var file = internalFiles.next();
    var copySheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheets()[0];
    var srcValues = copySheet.getRange("B3:P" + copySheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(3)).getValues();
    values = [...values, ...srcValues];
    file.moveTo(moveToG);
  }
  pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(3) + 1, 2, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the Spreadsheet is retrieved from "uploadFolder" folder. And, the values are retrieved from "B3:P" of the 1st tab for each Spreadsheet, and those values are appended from the column "B" of "pasteSheet" sheet.

#### Note:

- In this modification, from your showing script, the last row is retrieved from the column "C". But, if you want to use the last row of the data range, I think that you can also use `getLastRow()`.

#### References:

- [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)
- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- [moveTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#movetodestination)